# AttributeError type object Person has no attribute id

Tags: python, django

I created a edit form to edit the name of a person. Based on related Stackoverflow answers on this subject I changed my model and view, but even after the changes the follow error persists:

> AttributeError at /persion/4/edit type object 'Person' has no
>   attribute 'id'

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.person_edit, name='person_edit'),
```

views.py

```
def person_edit(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PersonForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.name = request.person_text
            obj.save()
            return redirect('/person/index.html',context)
    else:
        form = PersonForm(instance=obj)
    return render(request, 'person/edit_person.html', {'form': form})
```

edit_person.html

```
{% block content %}
<form action ="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
{%endblock content %}
```

**Update**
Changed the views.py to:

```
def person_edit(request, pk):
    Person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PersonForm(request.POST, instance=Person)
        if form.is_valid():
            Person = form.save(commit=False)
            Person.name = request.POST['person_text']
            Person.save()
            return redirect('/person/index.html',context)
    else:
        form = PersonForm(instance=Person)
    return render(request, 'person/edit_person.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: How do `index.html` and `edit_person.html` look like?

Comment: @DeepSpace see updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your else clause, you are passing a class - Question, but I presume your code actually has Person - instead of an instance. You should pass `obj` like you do in the other clause.

(Next time, please post your actual code, and the *full* traceback.)

Comment: oops. mixed some code. edited the question. the error is now: type object 'Person' has no attribute 'person_text'

Comment: No. Firstly you changed something completely different to what I suggested, and secondly that change could not possibly give the error you state (`request` is not Person). Please show the **actual code**.

Comment: I updated the question with actual code + the adjustments you suggested. It is working now.